# Syslog application as a serverless

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless, azure-monitoring

We have a nodejs application running on an on-prem server, which will monitor the Syslog file(Centralized Syslog server). If any errors/warnings reported in the Syslog file then this application will read the error and create a ticket in the ServiceNow. Got a requirement to run the application as a serverless(Azure functions). Can we do it or we will have to configure a Centralized server on the Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not quite sure what you exactly want to know, but maybe you can integrate Azure service health alerts with ServiceNow by using a webhook.